# Why an allocated array gets unallocated when it is passed to a subroutine?

Tags: fortran, allocatable-array

Passing an allocatable array via actual argument to a subroutine whose corresponding dummy argument is defined as an allocatable array:

```
module m
  real, allocatable :: a(:,:)
end module m

module m2
contains
  subroutine p(c)
    implicit none
    real, allocatable, intent(out):: c(:,:)
    write(*,*) 'allocated?=', allocated(c)
  end subroutine p
end module m2

program main
  use m, only : a
  use m2, only: p
  implicit none

  allocate(a(3,3))
  write(*,*) 'allocated?=', allocated(a)
  call p(a)

end program main
```

The output:

```
allocated?= T 
allocated?= F
```

The first is as expected, but why the allocated status becomes false, as is indicated by the second output?

Comment: Because you have `intent(out)`. We probably have a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocatable dummy arguments that have `intent(out)` are automatically deallocated when the procedure is entered according to thevstandard. The intent also affects the allocation status, not just the values inside.

It actually makes a very good sense. If it is `intent(out)`, any previous allocation status should not matter.